# Yii2 - Url Manager - Specific rule failing

Tags: regex, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-urlmanager

I have the following url:

http://example.com/user/login

If I input the url in the browser, it matches de rule:

```
'<module:user>/<slug:[\w\-]+>' => '<module>/<slug>'
```

If I create the url:

```
Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(["user/index", "slug" => "login"]);
```

It should create the same url as above but instead it creates:

```
http://example.com/user/index?slug=login
```

But If I change the rule to:

```
'<module:user>/<slug:[\w\-]+>' => '<module>/index'
```

It works ok, any ideas why? I guess for some reason:

1. It is passing slug empty to  or
2. It is an invalid value.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's doing that but probably because by the book it should be `'user/<slug:[\w\-]+>' => 'user/index'`.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `slug` is part of the route pattern: `'<module>/<slug>'`. So `<slug:[\w\-]+>` is not treated as a named GET param, but as a part of the route. That means that URL `/user/something` will point to route `user/something` without any GET params.

You should not use the same name for route patterns and named params. You should either use different name:

```
'<module:user>/<action:[\w\-]+>/<slug:[\w\-]+>' => '<module>/<action>'
```

Or hardcode action for specified rule (as you already did in second example):

```
'<module:user>/<slug:[\w\-]+>' => '<module>/index'
```

Note that this will also match standard actions, like `user/view`.

Comment: thanks for answering. What I am trying to do is use one of this GET params value as an action. I have tried changing its name from "slug" to "itest", and it does not work either. It seems we can not use GET params as action but we can for controller? that does not seem right. any ideas?

Comment: Which GET param you want to use as action? This is possible, but you cannot use the same name for get param and route pattern.

Comment: In example get param would be "myitem", how could I use it as action?

Comment: This not explain anything. Please update your question with info which route should point to which URL.